# Make a meteor publication reactive to time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to make a subscription reactive to a certain publication query.

My publication is as follows:

```
Meteor.publish('allData', function(){
    return Data.find({TTL: {$gt: new Date()}})
})
```

As you can see, the documents contain a TTL field. As long as the Time To Live is still greater that the current time, it can be sent to the client, if not, it shouldn't.

the subscription:

```
this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('allData')
})
```

On the initial load, all data is fine, but whenever the TTL expires, the document remains on the client unless I reload the page. Is there anyway to handle this reactively, making the expired documents disappear from the client?

Comment: The problem is that `new Date()` is not reactive data, and the publication isn't re-evaluated as time changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of ReactiveVar and an autorun did the trick for me. It's possible that this is overkill, but it works.

```
let cutoffTimestamp = new ReactiveVar();

Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    cutoffTimestamp.set(Date.now() - 1);
}, 60000);

Meteor.publish("myPub", function() {
    this.autorun(function() {
        return myCollection.find({ timestamp: { $gte: cutoffTimestamp.get(); } });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Johan, do you think Michel Floyd's answer is similar to yours? Considering it uses a reactive package in stead of a reactiveVar?

Comment: Michel's answer is good because it makes time a reactive data source, so it addresses your specific question. My answer showcases how to make something reactive that isn't, and might be of benefit to other people who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package to make time itself *reactive* then do:

client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allDataSince',Chronos.currentTime());
```

server:

```
Meteor.publish('allDataSince', t => Data.find({ TTL: { $gt: t }}));
```

Comment: This makes sense, and resembles Johan Althoff's answer, yet it doesn't seem to work. Can this have something to do with the fact that I'm working in the `/imports` folder?

Comment: Possibly - you might have to import Chronos

Comment: Meteor publish functions do not handle reactivity by themselves. You should put reactivity inside `autorun` inside your publish function. Then `chronos` can work. To get support for `autorun`, you should use [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) package.

Comment: Thanks @Mitar - I changed the answer to use reactive time in the subscription instead of the publication itself.